# Button outside the <form> is not triggering its onSubmit function

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am creating a Popup screen. Here is the code so far -

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { TasksCollection } from '../api/TasksCollection'


const TaskForm = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("")
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)
    const [deadline, setDeadline] = useState("")

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault()

        if(deadline){
            TasksCollection.insert({
                text: text.trim(),
                createdAt: new Date(),
                deadline : deadline,
            })
        }

        setText("")
        setDeadline("")
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <form className='task-form' id = "popup-form" onSubmit = {handleSubmit}>
            <button 
                type= "button"
                onClick = {() => {
                    if(!text) return
                    setClicked(true)
                }}>
                    Set Deadline
            </button>                
        </form>

        {clicked ? 
            <div className='popup'>
                <div className="popup-inner">
                    <label>Deadline: </label>

                    <input
                        type = "date"
                        onChange = {(e) => setDeadline(e.target.value)}/>

                    <button 
                        className= "button1" 
                        form = "popup-form"
                        type = "submit"
                        onClick={() => {
                                setClicked(false)
                            }}>
                            Add Task
                    </button>

                    <button 
                        className="button2" 
                        onClick={() => {
                            setClicked(false)
                        }}>
                            &times;
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        : ""}
    </div>
    )
}

export default TaskForm
```

I have made a useState boolean variable called `clicked`. When it turns `true`, it starts to render a popup screen. This popup screen wants to set value for another useState variable, `deadline`. Ultimately I want to add the deadline information to my `TasksCollection` mongoDB collection, which I am struggling to achieve.

When `clicked` becomes true, the popup screen appears. In that screen there is an `Add Task` button, which doesn't trigger the `handleSubmit` function. Could someone point why?

Comment: @Phil I am seeing a lot of posts suggesting the same solution given in the link. But that is not helping me. Notice that the `Add Task` button does have `form = "popup-form" in it. But its still not working :/

Comment: Oops, so sorry I didn't notice that. What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a timing issue. I'd say the button is being removed from the DOM before it's had a chance to trigger the *submit* event for the form.

Instead of trying to hide the modal at the same time as submit the form, I would simply let the submit handler hide it

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  setClicked(false);

  // ...
}
```

You can then remove the `onClick` prop from your *"Add Task"* button.

[image: Edit nervous-merkle-th2pgq]

Comment: @ParthGupta I also had success in using `setTimeout(setClicked, 0, false)` in the `onClick` handler but I felt my answer was more _the React way_.